# Printing doc file using cocoa

Tags: cocoa

Is it possible to print a doc file using cocoa application?
If possible please give some suggestions.
I printed pdf and image files.. But i didn't get any solution for doc files.

Thanks in advance,
Ramesh.P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Word Document format is understood by NSAttributedString. It's displayed by NSTextView. The question you're really asking is "how do I print the contents of an attributed string," which reduces to "how do I print the contents of an NSTextView" at its simplest.

Even if you're not displaying the text view to the user, you'll still need an off-screen one with the desired settings to print it easily.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for your valuable reply. Now i am able to print doc file using attributed string and textview. But i am not able to print the xls files.

Comment: That is a separate issue - mark this question answered and post a new one with the details of what you tried and what you're seeing as a result.

Comment: Hello Guys, Can you pls reply with code of Print functionality for a NSTextView content as well as webView content ?

Comment: Sid: Post a separate question and include what you've tried, what you've read, and what's not working. That is far more likely to get you a helpful response.